# How to iterate over a hive table row by row and calculate metric when a specific condition is met?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a requirement as below:

I am trying to convert a MS Access table macro loop to work for a hive table. The table called `trip_details` contains details about a specific trip taken by a truck. The truck can stop at multiple locations and the type of stop is indicated by a flag called `type_of_trip`. This column contains values like `arrival`, `departure`, `loading` etc.

The ultimate aim is to calculate the dwell time of each truck (how much time does the truck take before beginning for another trip). To calculate this we have to iterate the table row by row and check for trip type.

A typical example look like this:

Do while end of file:

1. Store the first row in a variable.
2. Move to the second row.
3. If the type_of_trip = Arrival:
   Move to the third row
4. If the type_of_trip = End Trip:
   Store the third row
   Take the difference of timestamps to calculate dwell time
5. Append the row into the output table

End

What is the best approach to tackle this problem in hive?

I tried checking if hive contains a keyword for loop but could not find one. I was thinking of doing this using a shell script but need guidance on how to approach this.

I cannot disclose the entire data but feel free to shoot any questions in the comments section.

**Input**

**Trip ID**   **type_of_trip**    **timestamp**            **location**

```
1         Departure       28/5/2019 15:00      Warehouse  
1         Arrival         28/5/2019 16:00      Store  
1         Live Unload     28/5/2019 16:30      Store  
1         End Trip        28/5/2019 17:00      Store
```

**Expected Output**

**Trip ID**  **Origin_location**  **Destination_location** **Dwell_time**

```
1        Warehouse        Store                2 hours
```

Comment: obfuscate data and provide input example with desired output based on the same input

Comment: Edited the question. Let me know if it is still unclear

Comment: I’m not an expert. As I understand, you want some sequential pass over the data. But Hadoop is a distributed DB, so the data is not supposed to be stored on one machine, and therefore for loop doesn’t make sense. Btw, even in case of sql usually  no ordering of data is usually guaranteed, and I think you also can’t rely on any ordering in Hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need loop for this, use the power of SQL query.

Convert your timestamps to seconds (using your format specified `'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'`), calculate min and max per trip_id, taking into account type, subtract seconds, convert seconds difference to `'HH:mm'` format or [any other format you prefer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
with trip_details as (--use your table instead of this subquery
select stack (4,
1,'Departure'   ,'28/5/2019 15:00','Warehouse', 
1,'Arrival'     ,'28/5/2019 16:00','Store',  
1,'Live Unload' ,'28/5/2019 16:30','Store',  
1,'End Trip'    ,'28/5/2019 17:00','Store' 
) as (trip_id, type_of_trip, `timestamp`, location)
)

select trip_id, origin_location, destination_location,
       from_unixtime(destination_time-origin_time,'HH:mm') dwell_time
  from
(
select trip_id,
       min(case when type_of_trip='Departure' then unix_timestamp(`timestamp`,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm') end) origin_time,
       max(case when type_of_trip='End Trip'  then unix_timestamp(`timestamp`,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm') end) destination_time,
       max(case when type_of_trip='Departure' then location  end) origin_location,
       max(case when type_of_trip='End Trip' then location  end) destination_location
  from trip_details 
 group by trip_id
)s;
```

Result:

```
trip_id origin_location destination_location    dwell_time  
1   Warehouse   Store   02:00
```

Comment: @code_crusher See test here:http://demo.gethue.com/hue/editor?editor=339739